# How to fetch a query result on different column when we use UNION in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to display a MySQL query result in that form

**Title 1 Title 2 Title3**.

with this query :

`SELECT title as titre1 FROM sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 1 
UNION
SELECT title as titre2 from sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 2
UNION
SELECT title as titre3 FROM sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 3`

but the result displayed in this form

**Title 1** with the different ROWS (title1,2 and 3).

any idea to help thanks !

Comment: Provide your table structure with sample data set

Comment: Yes... a UNION will do exactly that... add rows. You need a JOIN or a subSELECT to add columns. But to do either you need to specify some additional logic. Is ID_sequence the primary key of the table title? If not, which title should be on the same row as which other title... what's the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION`'ing data will combine various data sets into a common column structure, with a row per each.

What you are looking for in this case is a subquery for each sequence, return as a column.  This should do the trick.  Please note that if your subquery returns more than one row, then you will get an error, but this should not be an issue in your query since you are filtering on a single ID (assuming that ID_sequence in the primary key of the sequence table).

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT title as titre1 FROM sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 1 ) AS titre1 
, (SELECT title as titre2 from sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 2) AS titre2
, (SELECT title as titre3 FROM sequence  WHERE ID_sequence = 3) AS titre3
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1` would avoid the error (though arguably it's better to fail with an error than just return an arbitrary choice from several possible values!)

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` always adds *rows* onto a query - in a `UNION` of two queries the results from the second will appear underneath the results from the first.  So `UNION` won't do what you want here.

This query:

```
SELECT
  CASE ID_sequence WHEN 1 THEN title ELSE NULL END CASE as titre1,
  CASE ID_sequence WHEN 2 THEN title ELSE NULL END CASE as titre2,
  CASE ID_sequence WHEN 3 THEN title ELSE NULL END CASE as titre3
FROM sequence
WHERE ID_sequence > 0 AND ID_sequence < 3 ;
```

will give you three columns.  However in any given row two of the columns will be be blank which may or may not be what you want.

If you want to have all three columns with values in every row then you need to specify some relationship between them (i.e. which `Title1` goes with which `Title2` etc), then use a *self join*.  You haven't said what that relationship should be, so I can't give an example for that.